# TensorFlow and person recognition in video stream

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'd like to make app for recognition persons in video stream using tensorflow or keras.
What kind of neural network can i use? CNN or RNN? Shoud i analyze freame one by one or video stream as a whole? Any good source to learn?

Comment: Hi Jan, welcome to SO. This is way too broad. Please look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very large question. And a hard task.

I think, the easy way is to extract one frame by second if the source is a video stream.
Then use OpenCV to make a face detection.
Once you got the faces, feed a NN for recognitions.
Some links for face recognition in Deep Learning:

https://aboveintelligent.com/face-recognition-with-keras-and-opencv-2baf2a83b799

https://github.com/rajathkumarmp/FaceRecog-Keras/blob/master/faceRecog.ipynb